# How do I change all references to a string through out Sitecore tree and content?

Tags: content-management, content-tree

How do I change all references to a string through out Sitecore tree (Menus, links, Meta fields, etc.) and content?

Is there a easy way with built in tools or Powershell?

Comment: You need to be more precise. What do you mean by "all references to a string"?

Comment: You may start with installing Sitecore PowerShell Extensions and then review the related docs. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

Comment: OOTB - https://sitecorediaries.org/2021/09/06/sitecore-tips-search-and-replace/

Comment: jrap-The built in search and replace will rename tree nodes, rich text box content, nav items, etc.?